# Lexical analyser for Python - Ignore comment line

Tags: java, python, regex, lexical

So, I have to do a Lexical Analyser for Python in Java, everything is basically working but I can't seem to find a way to ignore comment lines using regex expressions. I created ArrayLists with reserved words, operating signs, comparison signs, etc. This is what I have so far:

```
    int encontrouLista = 0;

    token = token.replaceAll("[#](.)*","");

    if (token.contains(" ")){
        write.println("espaço em branco");
        token = token.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }        
    else if (token.contains("\n")){
        write.println("quebra de linha");
        token = token.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "");
    }

    for (Entry<String, ArrayList> entry : listas.entrySet()) {
        if (encontrouLista==1) break;
        if (token.length() > 0 && entry.getValue().contains(token)) {
            write.println(token + " pertence a " + entry.getKey());
            encontrouLista = 1;
        }
    }

    if (encontrouLista == 0 && !token.matches("^\\s*$")) {

        if (token.matches("[A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z_]*")) {
            write.println(token + " identificador");
            encontrouLista = 1;
        } else if (token.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            write.println(token + " numérico inteiro");
            encontrouLista = 1;
        } else if (token.matches("[0-9]+[.][0-9]+")) {
            write.println(token + " numérico real");
            encontrouLista = 1;
        } else {
            write.println(token + " não reconhecido");
        }
    }
```

I tried to use this line to ignore the comment lines:

```
token = token.replaceAll("[#](.)*","");
```

But I think that because of this "if" the code is considering the comment as an "identificador" instead of ignoring it:

```
        if (token.matches("[A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z_]*")) {
            write.println(token + " identificador");
            encontrouLista = 1;
        }
```

Am I using the correct regex expression? Also, I need to find a way to define things inside the "" for prints.

Answer (score 0):

```
(#[^\n]*\n$)
```

Here is the working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY1hU9/1)

Comment: When I use this #[^\n]*\n$ the "#" goes to the "não reconhecido" else (not recognized) and the comment goes to the if referring to the "identificador".